# Tutorial for a stereo Phaser in C++?

Tags: phase, sound

I was searching for a tutorial on how to implement a stereo Phaser in C++. All i´ve found was sourcecode with little or no explanations which did´nt help me much. Does anyone know a Tutorial with which i can learn and understand how to implement a stereo Phaser in C++? By the way im using the Juce Plugin.

Comment: I am closing this question, since it is implementation specific. You might want to rephrase it and ask for generic algorithm how to implement a stereo phaser effect. A nice starting point is the [DAFX book by Zolzer](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/dafx_book.pdf). Please see the page no. 86.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this [MusicDSP Phaser code](http://musicdsp.org/archive.php?classid=4#78) and discussion by Ross Bencina? It is commented, and says that its implemented to be "clear, not efficient". Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Felix - I went through this all last year.  I think you need to break it into separate parts. There's unlikely to be a specific JUCE Phasor tutorial out there - I couldn't find one either.

And, writing this stuff gets relatively complicated relatively quickly.

So split it into the following steps:

(a) Get a plugin working (I presume you are thinking about a plugin) in JUCE that does something basic.  You need to know how to get a controller on the screen and have it control a value in the audio processing thread. A volume and pan control would be a good first project. That's hard enough the first time. Visit the JUCE forum if you get stuck on this bit - and there's a good example included in the distribution.

Once that's sorted, on to the fun stuff:

(b) get a phasor working in a high-level mock up in Reaktor, MAX/MSP or something where you can drag audio processing modules around quickly.  (Or Csound, or puredata...)  There are undoubtedly lots of ways of making a phaser work in stereo.  And you might want to experiment or investigate how effects you already like work.

(c) identify the separate components in your phasor (probably an LFO, an all-pass filter and maybe some other bits).  Unlike complete phasers, you can probably find a well documented oscillator or all-pass filters

(d) work out how to implement those components in C++ (the examples will make more sense now you've done a mock up or two).   You may want to test them separately (does the LFO actually oscillator, does the all-pass filter work).

(e) Glue it all together into a working phaser.

I assume you've seen these? 
http://music.columbia.edu/pipermail/music-dsp/1998-August/053675.html
http://www.dsprelated.com/showcode/177.php

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I´ve already seen these tutorials and im doing a project toghether with a friend for university. We already have the standard plugin which can produce sound with up to three oscillators. Now we wanted to implement the effects but i had a hard time finding something useful for a phaser. :)

Comment: Felix, sounds like  you're well on your way then.  I'd jump straight to experimentation in puredata or something then.  

There's lots of information on the individual building blocks out there, e.g. http://freeverb3vst.sourceforge.jp/allpass.shtml, https://christianfloisand.wordpress.com/tag/all-pass-filter/ - good luck! Jim.